# Need to update substring in last line of few files having last line start with fixed string in linux

Tags: linux, grep

I need to update the text between first and second pipe of the string in all the file whose last line starts with particular string. Kindly help me find the linux command

File `abc.txt` contains below data:

```
Name|city|salary
xyz|pun|450000
Footer|355|02052019|895
```

there are other files in directory however I need to update only files whose last line start with `Footer`. Text to be updated is text between the first and second occurrence of `|`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the output should be, but this changes the second filed to some new, if first field is `Footer`

```
awk '$1=="Footer" {$2="new"}1' FS="|" OFS="|" abc.txt
Name|city|salary
xyz|pun|450000
Footer|new|02052019|895
```

Answer (score 0):

switch to the working directory first.

Initial file as below:

```
Name|city|salary
xyz|pun|450000
Footer|355|02052019|895
```

The script starts here:

```
srch="Footer"   # keyword to search at last of file.

for file_name in `ls`   # iterate all files in current directory
    do
    last_line_first_word="`tail -1 $file_name | cut -d "|" -f 1-1`"   # first word of the last line

    if [ "$srch" == "$last_line_first_word" ]   # if last word match proceed with replace
        then
        awk -F "|" '{$2="replace_string"; print; }' $file_name > dummy.txt  # replace second column with user string
        sed -i 's/ /|/g' dummy.txt   # replace <spaces> with "|" 
        sed -i '' 's/ /|/g' dummy.txt  # replace <spaces> with "|" [ In MAC ]
        mv dummy.txt  $file_name        # rename to original filename
        echo "File modified ->> "$file_name
    fi
    echo "File NOT modified "$file_name
done
```

Resultant file:

```
Name|replace_string|salary
xyz|replace_string|450000
Footer|replace_string|02052019|895
```

Hope this helps.

Logs:

```
File NOT modified Applications
File NOT modified Desktop
File NOT modified Documents
File NOT modified Downloads
File NOT modified IdeaProjects
File NOT modified Library
File NOT modified Movies
File NOT modified Music
File NOT modified Pictures
File NOT modified Public
File NOT modified PycharmProjects
File modified ->> test.txt
File NOT modified test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is to use `sed` to substitute values for the first set of number after the first `'|'`. You can use the `sed` substitution form `sed '/locate/s/find/replace/' file` where you would locate the line beginning `^Footer` and find `|[0-9][0-9]*` and replace the number there with whatever you like (say `|322` instead of `355`)

You can make the change in-place by providing the `-i` option to `sed`. For you that would look like:

```
$ sed -i '/^Footer/s/|[0-9][0-9]*/|322/' file
```

and the resulting data file after the change:

```
$ cat file
Name|city|salary
xyz|pun|450000
Footer|322|02052019|895
```

There are several alternative ways to approach this.